# How to groupby a column and agg as a list another column in Dask DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I have a Dask DataFrame from which I want to groupby a column and agg as a list  other columns.

e.g: `ddf.groupby('group_id')['name', 'department'].agg(list)`

Is there a approach through which i can achieve it?

Comment: maybe not the most elegant(/best) way of doing it could you try this?
`ddf.groupby('group_id')['name'].apply(list).compute()`

Comment: it throws a warning, would you be able to add a example using the time series data set `dask.datasets.timeseries()`

Comment: @user7440787 which one is the warning you get? I can see two: the first is related to the lack of metadata and can easily fixed adding this info. The second is a `FutureWarning` and it's related to how the dataset was built. This is fixed for `dask.__version__ >=1.2.2`

Comment: @rpanai Using the timeseries dataset and the following command:
`df.groupby('name')['x'].apply(list).compute()`;
I get only a metadata warning:  
`__main__:1: UserWarning: \`meta\` is not specified, inferred from partial data. Please provide `meta` if the result is unexpected.`

Comment: @user7440787 you can easily fix adding a meta. From `df = dask.datasets.timeseries()` you can use either `df.groupby(["id"])['name'].apply(list, meta=pd.DataFrame).compute()` or ` df.groupby(["id"])['name'].apply(list, meta='str').compute()`. You should put as answer so it's easier for other user to find the solution. The please comment here so i can upvote you.

Comment: @rpanai thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Using dask's time series as an example, column aggregation into lists can be achieved using:

```
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
df = dask.datasets.timeseries()
name_aggr = df.groupby(["id"])['name'].apply(list, meta=pd.DataFrame).compute()
```

Thanks @rpanai for the help!